# Composite or Graph API - deleting multiple records based on external Id

Tags: rest, composite, graph

I've tried to leverage the new Composite Graph API to delete records for which I only know the external Id.

I've tried 2 ways and both of which have failed

- Method 1:
  In a single request:
  a subrequest to GET the record
  a subrequest to DELETE the record using `{referenceId.Id}` in the URL

  Result: Failed
- Method 2:
  In a single request
  a subrequest to PATCH the record
  a subrequest to DELETE the record using `{referenceId.Id}` in the URL

  Result: Endpoint not supported in Composite Graph API:
  `/v51.0/sobjects/Account/{AccountToDelete.Id}`

Has anyone successfully done a delete using the Composite Graph API?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as @sfdxfox said, you should better prefer `Composite API` because [`Graph API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph_introduction.htm) provides an enhanced way to perform composite requests, that is, it serves other purposes (e.g. allows to assemble a more complicated and complete series of related objects and records).
But if you still want to use `Graph API` to delete records by external id, you can make the following request:

```js
POST https://{{instance_url}}/services/data/v50.0/composite/graph
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
X-PrettyPrint: 1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "graphs" : [
    {
      "graphId" : "1",
      "compositeRequest" : [
        {
          "url" : "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/External_Id_Field__c/externalIdValue",
          "method" : "DELETE",
          "referenceId": "ref1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So in case if your external id field value is `unique`, you will get the next response:

```js
{
  "graphs": [
    {
      "graphId": "1",
      "graphResponse": {
        "compositeResponse": [
          {
            "body": {
              "attributes": {
                "type": "Account",
                "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/0011j00000yM0ReAAK"
              },
              "Id": "0011j00000yM0ReAAK",
              "ExternalId__c": "externalIdValue"
            },
            "httpHeaders": {
              "Last-Modified": "Thu, 28 Jan 2021 23:04:41 GMT"
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "referenceId": "ref1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isSuccessful": true
    }
  ]
}
```

If your external id field value is **`not unique`** you'll get a response with `"httpStatusCode": 300`. In this case you should retrieve the records ids by external id using standard REST API:

```js
GET https://{{instance_url}}/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/External_Id_Field__c/externalIdValue
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
```

Response:

```js
[
    "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/0011j00000yM0ReAAK",
    "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/0011j00000yM0RgAAK"
]
```

And then having the ids of found records delete them using [sObject Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) endpoind:

```js
DELETE https://{{instance_url}}/services/data/v50.0/composite/sobjects?ids=0011j00000yM0ReAAK,0011j00000yM0RgAAK
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
```

However, I don't believe it is possible to do it in a single composite request with 2 subrequests.

**NOTE.** You can delete up to 200 records at a time

Answer (score 1):

Use the Composite API, not the Graph API. The latter is used to insert and update related records. The first subsequent would be a get, the second the delete call.